# Regex to match position from right to left

Tags: regex

I hope you can help me, I'm studying how to make a regex and now I have this problem:

Write a regex that accepts strings with 0 and 1 and that has a 1 on position 5 from right to left.

e.g. 10000 is accepted because it has an 1 on the position 5 from right to left or 010000, 0010000 or 1110000  are accepted.

I was thinking with something like: (0+1)*+1(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)(0+1)

Comment: Like [`^[01]*1[01]{4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/H3RSLq/1)?

Comment: Awesome, thanks, can you explain me how did you get to that?

Comment: This solution is posted twice below. See ap's explanation, he was the first to correct his regex to look like mine.

Comment: Are you working with mathematical regular expressions or programming regular expressions? The syntax you use looks more like math.

Comment: mathematical regular expressions, i forgot to add that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
1[01]{4}$
```

If you want to match full input then use:

```
^[01]*1[01]{4}$
```

Here `1[01]{4}$` ensures that we have 4 digits of `0` and `1` after we match `1` thus making `1` at 5th position from right to left.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JDTL46/1)

Answer (score 0):

Well - think of it this way. It needs to be as many 1s and 0s as you please, followed by a 1, followed by 4 more ones or zeroes.

So:

```
my_regex = 
    "^[01]*" +  // Starts with One or zero, zero or more times 
    "1" +       // Followed by a one
    "[01]{4}$"  // Followed by four things, which could be either zero or one, before ending.
```

Your (0 + 1) syntax looks foreign to me. I'm using character classes to specify the [01] things but you could use (0|1) in their place, which is what your attempt looks more like.

The full thing, together, is `^[01]*1[01]{4}$`